# Python requests not working?

Tags: python, python-requests

When I go to import `requests` on Windows 7, it comes up with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19lAL.png):

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Please specify the other client to connect to: _
```

What do I do?

Comment: You have a file named `requests.py` somewhere, rename it.

Comment: What happens when you just hit ENTER there? If you get a traceback you can next look at `requests.__file__` to see *where* it is located.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I can't find the file. You're right that there is an interferance, but I'm not sure where. I can't seem to get it to chuck me the location. Is there any way I can trace what files are executed?

Comment: you could have had a `requests.pyc` file kicking around there too. Glad it was solved. You can run `python -v` to trace imports next time.